# Decode JSON Web Token (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, json-web-token

Basically I want to decode a base64 encoded JWT to extract the information in the body part.

I tried searching for possibilities to decode the token but all JWT Nuget-Packages don't work with my Xamarin.Android project since Mono doesn't have the assemblies and on their own forums there are no further informations about this topic.

Do you guys have a solution for this? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the portable Version of JWT: https://github.com/senzacionale/jwt-portable-dotnet 
It's also available on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.JWT/

There is one error in the decode example. It's `JWT.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException` instead of `JWT.SignatureVerificationException`

Comment: I would give you a son if I could ! thank you so much !

Comment: @DavidNoreña dafaq